# How can I fetch last digits from a filename

Tags: r

I have files with the following file names. I want the number in the file name (like 2,3,10,11):

```
filename2
filename3
filename10
file name11
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: `stringi::stri_extract_last_regex('filename10', '[0-9]+')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\\d` regular expression will match digits, the `+` says to take any number of digits, and the `$` says to pick them off where they are at the end of the string.  So the following will grab only those digits that appear at the end of the string.

```
file <- c(paste0("filename", c(2, 3, 10)), "file name11")

library(stringr)
str_extract(file, "\\d+$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex will do the job for you!

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all('filename12',"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?")[[1]]
[1] "12"
```

Comment: Note that this will pick out every number in the file name. That may or may not be desirable, depending on how structured the filenames are.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`

```
sub(".*[^0-9]+(\\d+)$", "\\1", file)
```